# Is SSH enabled by default on ubuntu 20.10 64bit for raspberry pi 4 - ARM64

Tags: ssh, raspberrypi, 20.10, putty

Is SSH enabled by default on ubuntu 20.10 64bit for raspberry pi 4 - ARM64

I want to configure my Raspberry Pi 4 with Ubuntu 64 as a headless install.  it will be wired ethernet.

I can ping the Pi but ssh fails to connect from Putty 'Network error. Connection Refused'

I have tried adding a ssh. file on the boot partition (from notepad, saving the file as 'ssh', no extn and using save as *.*)

any help much appreciated.

matt

Comment: Ubuntu Server 20.10 does indeed include openssh-server, and it's enabled in the default install. Ubuntu Desktop 20.10 does not include openssh-server.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, ssh is enabled on Ubuntu Server 20.10. You need to wait a little after the first boot, I think it is expanding the filesystem first which takes time.